# How to have multiple string equals something?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a case where if the input equals any of these"@ ) ( & 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0" then the input is ok and the program continues running. But if it does not then it sends the print statement. Obviously I could keep creating more and more "s.equals()" but this seems very inefficient. Is there another way that I am missing to accomplish the same goal but with less code?

```
// check here for invalid characters
for (String s : inputString.split("")) {
    if (s.equals("@") || s.equals(")") || s.equals("(") || s.equals("&") || s.equals("1") || s.equals("2") || s.equals("3") || s.equals("4")) {
        continue;

    } else {
        System.out.println("NO GOOD");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: try: `if("@()&1234".contains(c))` ...

Comment: Keep them in a list and check if it contains it or regex.

Comment: Hi, you could use a negative regex to check for invalid characters with the input string. For example, if the string matches the pattern `[^0-9&()]` it has an invalid character.

Comment: if (Arrays.asList("@",")","(","&","1","2","3","4").contains(s)) { ... }

Comment: if (s.matches("@|\\\)|\\\(|&|1|2|3|4")) { ... }